# Search text file that created today by partial name and copy over to another folder in powershell

Tags: powershell

I just wandering how can I search a text file that created today by partial name and copy over to another folder in power shell.

Example:
I have the following files:

```
LS_TA__Importing__123.TXT (created today)
LS_TA__Importing__145.TXT (created yesterday)
LS_TA__Importing__287.TXT (created yesterday)
LS_TA__Importing__687.TXT (created day after yesterday)
```

How could I use power shell to search for the text file that created today by partial name (example LS_TA__Importing__*.TXT) and copy over to another folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Get-ChildItem`

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Location -Include "LS_TA__Importing__*.TXT" -Recurse
```

Then you can pipe `|` it to `Move-Item`

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Location -Include "LS_TA__Importing__*.TXT" -Recurse | 
    Move-Item -Destination C:\OtherLocation
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get-ChildItem and select only files that were created today

```
Get-ChildItem 'LS_TA__Importing__*.TXT' | where {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date}
```

and pipe the results to Move-Item

```
Get-ChildItem 'LS_TA__Importing__*.TXT' | where {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date} | Move-Item -Destination .\OtherFolder
```